# C++ ,Count positive and negative numbers and compute the average of numbers) Write a program that reads an unspecified number of integers

Tags: c++, loops

"Count positive and negative numbers and compute the average of numbers Write a program that reads an unspecified number of integers , determines how many positive and negative values have been read, and computes the total and average of the input values (not counting zeros). Your program ends with the input 0. Display the average as a double.  where did i go wrong??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
            int num= 0;
            int sum=0;
            int pos=0;
            int neg=0;
            double ave=0;
            cout << "Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: " ;
            cin >> num ;
            if (num%10==10) {
                while (num!=0) {
                    num/=10;
                    if (num%10>0) {
                        pos++;
                    }
            else if (num%10<0) {
                neg++;
            }
            sum+=num;
                }
            ave= (double)sum/(pos+neg);
            }
            cout <<"The number of positives are " << pos <<endl;
            cout <<"The number of negatives are " << neg <<endl;
            cout <<"The total is " << sum << endl;
            cout <<"The average is "<< ave << endl;
            return 0;

 }
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: where did i go wrong?

Comment: How are we supposed to know?  You did not tell what your code is doing and what it should be doing.

Comment: I'm new in here, sorry for my inexperince. this is what it shoud be doing:


. "Count positive and negative numbers and compute the average of numbers Write a program that reads an unspecified number of integers , determines how many positive and negative values have been read, and computes the total and average of the input values (not counting zeros). Your program ends with the input 0. Display the average as a double.

Comment: [**F**](http://ideone.com/RLCI2U)

Comment: and my code is showing the number of negatives, positives, total and average as "0"

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @Somoykhan You read an input value only once, not in a loop.

Comment: how should i make it inside in a loop?

Comment: @Somoykhan Put the `cin >> num;` inside a `do { } while(num != 0);` loop.

Comment: @Somoykhan do you want to read input multiple time or just one time?

Comment: @SudiptaKumarSahoo Read the _"question"_ again.

Comment: @SudiptaKumarSahoo once.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it is not evident from question, so i asked? is it wrong to ask doubt about question?

Comment: @Somoykhan _"once"_ Are you sure about that? Your requirement seems to expect you doing something different.

Comment: it should be like this, I mean the sample run:

Enter an integer, the output ends if it 0 : 1 2 -1 3 0
The number of positives is 3
The number of negatives is 1
The total is 5
The average is 1.25

Comment: @Somoykhan: Your question says "an unspecified number of integers", not "one integer".  You need the cin inside a loop.  Also `if (num%10==10)` will always be false (`num%10` will be between 0 and 9).  Finally I think your test should be `sum+=num; if (num==0) break;  if (num > 0) pos++; else neg++; `

Comment: You seem to have confused numbers with digits.

Comment: If i add the cin >> num ; inside of a loop, when i run it it doesnt ask for an input

Comment: @Somoykhan Why is the modulus operator, `%`, even being used in this assignment, given what was specified?  Maybe you should take 3 steps back and write a very simple program that inputs integers until a 0 is entered.  Forget about the averages, and negative / positive for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `char[]` to read input.
I have modified your program as follows;

```
int main()
{
    int sum=0;
    int pos=0;
    int neg=0;
    double ave=0;
    char arr[100] = {'\0',};

    std::cout << "Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: " ;  
    gets(arr);

    int index = 0;
    char ch[1];
    bool negativeNumber = false;

    while(true)
    {               
        ch[0] = arr[index++];
        if(ch[0] == ' ') // Check space and continue;
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(ch[0] == '0' || ch[0] == '\0') // check for 0 or NULL and break;
        {
            break;
        }
        if(ch[0] == '-') // Set flag if "-ve"
        {           
            negativeNumber = true;
            continue;
        }

        int digit = atoi(ch);
        if(negativeNumber)
        {
            digit *= -1;
            negativeNumber = false;
        }
        if(digit > 0)
        {
            pos++;
        }
        else if(digit < 0)
        {
            neg++;
        }
        sum += digit;
    }
    ave= (double)sum/(pos+neg);

    cout <<"The number of positives are " << pos <<endl;
    cout <<"The number of negatives are " << neg <<endl;
    cout <<"The total is " << sum << endl;
    cout <<"The sverage is "<< ave << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where is that atoi (ch) declared?

Comment: atoi() is a predefined function that converts a char pointer to int type.